# Sumar varias tablas usando condicional where y between

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Buenos dias vuelvo de nuevo con este detalle que no se como resolver, en mi base de datos **tengo 8 tablas** cada una de ellas cuenta con una columna de **cantidad** la cual **quiero sumar todas esas columnas y que me de un total dependiendo de la fecha que uno elija por medio de la condicional Where y between.**

**ya he intentado individual y si me arroja correctamente:**
SELECT sum(cantidad_doctor) from tbldoctores WHERE ExpenseDate BETWEEN '2020-09-01' AND '2020-09-31'

**Asi me da error!!:**
select ((select sum(cantidad_factura) from tblcontador)+(select sum(cantidad_doctor) from tbldoctores)+(select sum(cantidad) from tblecoentorno)+(select sum(cantidad) from tblentrada_plan)+(select sum(cantidad) from tblfacturas)+(select sum(cantidad) from tbltrabajadores) +(select sum(cantidad_envio) from tblmaquila)) WHERE ExpenseDate BETWEEN '2020-10-01' AND '2020-10-31'

**y todo junto con Union All pero me arroja las sumas por separado y no me detecta la condicional where between:**
SELECT sum(cantidad_doctor) from tbldoctores
union ALL
SELECT sum(cantidad_factura) from tblcontador
.
.
.
union ALL
select sum(cantidad) from tbltrabajadores) + (select sum(cantidad_envio) from tblmaquila
WHERE ExpenseDate BETWEEN '2020-09-01' AND '2020-09-31'

**Lo que requiero es que me de la sumatoria total de las columnas cantidades de todas las tablas con la condiconal Where y el between**

**Por favor si me pueden ayudar con esto se los super agradecería.**

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes datos relacionados en 8 tablas? ¿Las filas en las 8 tablas tienen algo en común (por ejemplo un ID)? ¿No es acaso un error de diseño el principal problema aquí?

Comment: Hola!! aca no agregamos resuelto a los titulos.. ya se ve en la pantalla principal cuando algo esta resuelto (se pinta de verde el cuadro de respuestas). Tambien, que agregues tu respuesta en la pregunta cuando hay una respuesta, no aporta nada a la pregunta y confunde...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select sum(cantidad_doctor) as total,"nombre_tabla"
from tbldoctores where 
expensedate between '2020-09- 
01' and '2020-09-31'
union Select 
sum(cantidad_factura) as total, 
"nombre_tabla" from tblcontador 
where expensedate between 
'2020-09-01' and '2020-09-31'
union consultaN
```

Para cada consulta debes evaluar la condición del rango de fechas para que por cada tabla se filtren esos campos, pongo otra columna "nombre_tabla" para que sepas a que tabla pertenece esa suma

En el ejemplo que ponías utilizando union el where solamente lo ponías a la última consulta no a la totalidad de los union por eso no filtraba bien, por eso el where va en cada tabla y debes usar unión, no union all

Ahora bien si quisieras saber el total general de todos esos sub totales que te dan cada tabla pues entonces tendrías que hacer esto

```
select sum(Total) from 
(select sum(cantidaddoctor) 
as total from tbldoctor 
where expensedate between 
'2020-09-01' and '2020-09- 
31' union select 
sum(cantidadfactura) as 
total from tblcontador where 
expensedate between '2020- 
09-01' and '2020-09-31') 
tabla;
```

Lo que se hace en esta consulta es que en el from se hace una consulta que es la que se encarga de hacer las sumas de cada tabla con los unión, una select dentro de un from es como si fuera una tabla no hay ninguna diferencia. En el select dentro del from utilizo las palabras as Total que es un alias que le doy a todas las sumas de cada tabla para entonces utilizar este alias en la consulta general que me va a sumar entonces todos los totales, por último después que termino la consulta dentro del from le doy el nombre tabla esto ultimo es opcional si quiero le doy nombre o no

Comment: Buenos dias mi estimado una pregunta a que te refieres en esa parte de ""nombre tabla from Tblcontador si ya estoy nombrando a la tabla despues del from?? es que ya lo hice como dijiste y puse ahi el nombre de la tabla y me da error, o como lo meteria es que estoy medio enredado ahorita con todo esto ya tengo varios dias con esta duda y nada que me sale, sobre la el union all si me da la suma de cada tabla pero quisiera que me lo diera en una sola cantidad, como lo haria ??

Comment: Lo del "nombre_tabla" es opcional simplemente te lo sugería para saber a de que tabla es ese total. Ej si tu tabla se llama doctores pues "nombre_tabla" seria "Doctores"  tienes que ponerlo entre comillas ya que ese campo lo estas sugiriendo tu, no existe es una cadena de texto y las cadenas de texto van entre comillas

Comment: Te edité la consulta revisa bien y dime

Comment: Mi hermano muchisimas gracias ahora si ya quedo resuleto y me da lo que tanto anhelaba que era la suma total de todas las tablas.